# IDE that allows "Find Usages" on custom event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

This is a scenario that happens to me alot:

I read code, and stumble over a line like this

```
$('#gotham').trigger('batman_arrived');
```

Now, how am I supposed to know which parts of the code actually listens to this event?
I don't want to have to do a freetext search of my entire project.

Anyone know if there exists an IDE that lets me do something like this?

Comment: Finding the general usage of this event name is possibly, although finding the usage of this event on this exact object (`$('#gotham')`) is impossible. The first task should be solvable with a simple regex.

Comment: The general usage would suffice. Alright, so if it's solvable with a regex, I think some IDE should implement it as a feature.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this can be done, but the single usable Javascript IDE for me, was Web Storm... This is sub-set of Intelij Idea for working with Javascript and Html, try it (if you haven't yet)...

Comment: Sure I know of WebStorm, it's great. I'm guessing this question might lead to a feature request to them, but I was hoping some IDE would already have implemented this.

Comment: for a comprehensive breakdown of IDEs : http://blue-walrus.com/2013/08/review-javascript-ides/